# Nginx subdomain: redirecting to wrong directory

Tags: nginx

I have a domain (let it be *example.com*). Also, I have a configured nginx web server, where *example.com* is pointed to the root directory **/var/www/example**.
Then, I wanted to point *service.example.com* to **/var/www/example**, and then point the original *example.com* to **/var/www/service**
Fisrt lines of nginx config for *service.example.com* look like this:

```
server {

    server_name service.example.com;

    root /var/www/example;

......
```

It works, and when I try to access service.example.com, I'm being redirected to the index file in /var/www/example.

Then, I made a config for example.com:

```
server {

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/service;

......
```

,but when I'm trying to access *example.com*, I see the index file of **/var/www/example**— as if I tried to access *service.example.com*.

So, how can I solve this problem, and see index file of **/var/www/service** when I'm trying to access *example.com*?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    root /var/www/service;
    server_name service.example.com;
}
```

reference: https://hackprogramming.com/how-to-setup-subdomain-or-host-multiple-domains-using-nginx-in-linux-server/

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in symlinks.

Some of them was not the symlinks in sites-enabled, but archive. So, nginx didn't handled them.

Problem was solved!